# Moving from android to sencha-touch

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2

I am creating an app on android but after hearing about sencha that it supports multiple platforms, so before choosing that i have some confusions about this framework. Please answer few questions

1. Will sencha apps will work only in web browsers? i.e. launching an app will open web browser first?
2. Android has built in database i.e. SQLite? does sancha supports it or has its own built in DBMS?
3. Can i use hardware features like camera(for barcode scanning)?
4. Does it support google maps
5. Is it possible to create homescreen widgets that runs on iphone,blackberry and android?
   any help in this regard will be highly appreciated

Comment: Please take some care in formatting your question, there is a preview available on the question page. I've modified it a bit for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too much information is available on the internet about Sencha Touch. Their latest version is Sencha Touch 2. I did explore that alternative a few months back (back then, they were still on version 1).

That being said, let me answer as many of your queries as I can.

1. Sencha Touch driven applications don't run in your web browser. They
   run natively on each platform you design for. However, they make use
   of the webkit engine integrated in you App. Therefore, launching you
   App will not open a browser page but will run your application
   (HTML5 by the way) within your App.
2. A preliminary search on their website has SQL Database mentioned. http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.feature.has-property-SqlDatabase. Not sure about how they integrate it. Perhaps a look into their SDK/ API and a few samples should clear that up. Alternatively, an I am just guessing here at this point, it might connect your website database, if one exists.
3. Harware features don't seem to be avialble at the moment. A quick look at their kitchnsink example should give you an idea of the components available for integration. http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/index.html
4. It does support Google Maps.
5. They do list an extension called `WIDGET` but the documnetation seems rather silent about functionality. Again, as mentioned earlier, a dive in to the SDK / API and a few examples might clear that up.

This here is their online Guide: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide

And this is a page to their Examples: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/example

I would still go ahead with Native App development as it gives you more flexibility over something like Sencha Touch.

Alternatively, if you would still like the one effort, multiple platform thingy, there are a few alternatives available.

1. http://www.phonegap.com/
2. http://www.appcelerator.com/
3. http://www.rhomobile.com/

Good luck with your app development. And I hope the info provided helps.... :-)

Comment: @JanshairKhan: You are welcome fella. And if you think the information is correct or helps you in anyway, you might consider selecting the response as the right answer. ;-)

Comment: So what would be the best choice among all of them ? phonegap? appcelerator, sencha or rhomobile to start with?

Comment: Well, I would go with phonegap. To my knowledge, it has been around for a while now and has really matured. But that is just my opinion.